# How do I access the camera/transform parameters in cv2.Stitcher?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I am trying to stitch together a bunch of microscope images, but I need to keep track of the physical location of each image. Before stitching, I know the coordinates of each individual image, but after stitching the Python method only returns the stitched image and some status flag.

How do I obtain the (affine) transformations that were automatically estimated in [cv2.Stitcher](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d48/samples_2python_2stitching_8py-example.html).stitch()?

I know the full pipeline can be viewed in the C++ source code and there's a high-level flow chart, but if I have to obtain those parameters that way, I basically have to re-implement cv2.Stitcher myself...

Comment: stitcher.stitch() looks like a convenience function that does a lot of things transparently. you can still use the stitching module's pipeline if you run the parts explicitly.

Comment: idk, start here, also open everything under "modules" https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d46/group__stitching.html looks like API docs mostly, so that's disappointing. I've never messed with this myself. it's a big complex module. if you find the docs lacking, file a bug report. then someone will probably poke the original author who should have some recollection and be the most qualified to improve it. there are C++ examples for stitching, among them a "detailed" one... did you see it? https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/dd8/samples_2cpp_2stitching_detailed_8cpp-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a python wrapper around the OpenCV stitching module: [stitching](https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching)

In this packge you can easily access the cameras parameter within the `stitch` method in the [Stitcher](https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching/blob/main/stitching/stitcher.py) class. See also the [tutorial](https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md#camera-estimation-adjustion-and-correction).

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of this package

Comment: Dear god, the SE jackpot! Thank you! It would be good if the OpenCV documentation referred to your Github. I was searching for ages and never encountered this.

Comment: Glad it helps! Feel free to add a PR to update the OpenCV Docs :)

Comment: I'll look into it !

Comment: Also, my compliments to your work. The wrapper stitching function worked out of the box on badly (non-uniformly) lit microscope images !

Comment: Thank you! But I must say that all the functionality comes from OpenCV, with the stitching package it's just (much) more convenient to use.